# Handling foreign characters in website running on python, tornado and redis

Tags: python, redis, tornado, hebrew

I've read through many of the related questions and am a bit unsure as to how to handle this situation.

The Basic Question: What is the best way to handle "foreign" (Hebrew, Greek, Aramaic?, etc.) characters in a website?

I get that I need to use UTF-8 encoding but the mechanics behind it are lost on me.

I am using tornado as my framework and am storing the data in redis.

My current implementation is to simply store the English keyboard equivalent in the data store and then rendering on a page with the appropriate Hebrew/Greek font (e.g. Bwhebb.ttf). This has worked, for the most part, but I am bumping up against some characters which are being CGI encoded which, in turn, causes the font method to break.

Comment: http://farmdev.com/talks/unicode/

Comment: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/printerFriendly/articles/Unicode.html - it is an article titled "The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)" - please go and read it: it is well-written and I believe it would be helpful to you.

Comment: Another good reading, specifically targeted to python 3 is http://diveintopython3.org/strings.html (the article on joelonsoftware is a nice reading but you can see it has been written almost 10 years ago)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the articles given in the comments.

Short answer though, store unicode in Redis, and if you're using Python 2.x, use unicode strings (`u""`) throughout. You may have to convert to unicode (`unicode()`) after retrieval from Redis, depending on what it gives you.

Answer (score 7):

You should save your text in unicode.

```
import redis
r = redis.Redis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)

greek = u'αβγδ'
greek, type(greek)
# (u'\u03b1\u03b2\u03b3\u03b4', <type 'unicode'>)

r.set(u"greek", greek)
# True
```

Though when you retrieve it, Redis will most probably give you a byte string, which is not what you want:

```
greek2 = r.get(u"greek")
greek2, type(greek2)
# ('\xce\xb1\xce\xb2\xce\xb3\xce\xb4', <type 'str'>)
```

You want to convert it to unicode like so:

```
greek2 = unicode(r.get(u"greek"), "utf-8")
greek2, type(greek2)
# (u'\u03b1\u03b2\u03b3\u03b4', <type 'unicode'>)
```

Comment: Thanks, Ian.  Ps. at the time if writing your rep is 1337.